# extract values from xml

Tags: python, regex, xml, awk, sed

QExtremely amateur programmer here, looking for your help.

I have to frequently edit xml files that look like this

```
    --- blah blah blah plenty xml stuff above ---
    <lex marker="mala" sentiment="negative"/>
    <lex marker="malas" sentiment="negative"/>
    <lex marker="maleducad\p{Ll}*" sentiment="negative" regex="true"/>
    <lex marker="mali\p{Ll}+sima\p{Ll}*" sentiment="negative" regex="true"/>
    <lex marker="mali\p{Ll}+simo\p{Ll}*" sentiment="negative" regex="true"/>
    --- blah blah blah plenty xml stuff below ---
```

And using a rather convoluted regex search and replace process I can extract ONLY the value of the marker attribute. (that is all I care for).

But it's time consuming and there must be pretty simple way in Python to look for the attribute marker="SOME_TEXT" part and plonk all the values into an array, and then afterwards print out that array (to a file). But I can't figure it out :(

I'm looking for a way that doesn't including importing any kind of XML library because I want to keep it as simple (and logical) as possible for my amateur programming mind to learn from) and I'm only interested in the data from that particular attribute anyway, and I care not for any of the rest of the file (or it's XML-ness).

I only ask in python because I think it's a language I'm keen to get into. but if you can think of a Linux Terminal way to do it (sed, awk e.t.c.) i'm happy to go that route too.

Comment: Use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching XML with regular expressions get too complicated, too fast. You really [should not do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Use a XML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.xml')
for elem in tree.findall('lex'):
    print elem.attrib['marker']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if in the future the bunch of files I get sent aren't xml files? that's why it would be good to have programmatic process that looks for a certain block of text, and preserves everything between that.

Comment: @user2122995: If in the future you are sent a bunch of files that aren't xml files *you adjust your code*. Right now you get XML, and an XML parser is the right tool. What if you were sent JSON data instead? Your regular expression wouldn't match the data in that format either.

Comment: Haha, okay, Fair enough. Rep given. Thank you